# xamarin studio for ios on windows?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

Yesterday at the xamarin webinar I asked if it was possible to install xamarin studio for IOS development on a windows machine and was given the answer that it was possible but developers usually went for visual studio. Today I've tried to find info about how to do this but can only find posts that it can only be done via Visual Studio. Most of the posts are a couple of months old though so which is the correct answer?

Comment: Possible doesn't necessarily mean easy.

Comment: I fail to see how this comment helps me or others who read this question? If you have a way I'd really appreciate a more detailed description.

Comment: I don't know much about this specifically, but I meant that when they said the answer was "it's possible", that doesn't necessarily mean "it's possible in a few clicks". If everything you're using is written in C# (or any other language compiled to CIL), you can just copy the assemblies and install any missing dependencies to the GAC. Otherwise you may have to compile from source or something.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I think your fears are true. Another post talks a little about this:

> [How to develop iOS app using Xamarin Studio on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16096218/how-to-develop-ios-app-using-xamarin-studio-on-windows/16158058#16158058)

The official [Xamarin documentation](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/introduction_to_xamarin_ios_for_visual_studio) also says pretty clearly that you need Visual Studio to do iOS development in Windows. On top of that, you also need a Mac on the network to compile the iOS project.

Answer (score 1):

1. Using ***Mac build Host*** you can do but you'll ***need the networked mac
   for developing and debugging too***.
2. or else you can use ***[Xamarin Live Player](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2017/05/xamarin-live-player-almost-takes-the-mac-out-of-ios-development/)*** using which you can
   ***debug,develop and deploy the app completely in windows*** without the
   help of any Apple system but to sign and release the app to appstore
   you will need Apple System though

Answer (score 0):

You can access Xamarin Studio from a Windows machine by accessing a remote Mac from services such as MacinCloud.com. Although you are not running Xamarin Studio directly on your Windows machine, the ability to access a Mac server for development allows you to run Xamarin Studio, and other Mac-only tools easily.