# Developing Xamarin apps for iOS using a VM with OS X installed

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, virtual-machine

I am interested in developing for Xamarin, but I only have a W10 laptop and no MAC. I have seen different answers to questions very similar to this one like these: [How to develop iOS app using Xamarin Studio on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16096218/how-to-develop-ios-app-using-xamarin-studio-on-windows?rq=1), [Xamarin Visual Studio IOS Development Without a Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25508487/xamarin-visual-studio-ios-development-without-a-mac?rq=1). Even though the accepted responses say it can't be done there are some others good answers that say it can be done. So my question is:

How can I develop iOS apps in Xamarin for Visual Studio 2015 without a MAC available, using some virtualization technology (thinking VMWare/VirtualBox since I don't have any experience in Hyper-V)?

Comment: I'm not totally sure about this, but I *think* Apple licenses OS X in such a way that running it in a VM on a Windows box is not permitted.  Or maybe they do stuff in software to prevent that from happening.  In any case, I don't hear about a lot of people doing this.

Comment: The questions this one (supposedly ) duplicates is just about developing for iPhone, what I ask is more technology specific (Xamarin) in one sense and broader on other as with Xamarin you could also develop for iPod and iPad.

Answer (score 7):

Installing a Mac VM is not trivial, and not acceptable by the terms of the EULA from Apple.  If you can swing it at all, I'd recommend picking up a Mac Mini ($500 ish).  This will make you legit, and you can just hook it up in a corner - or like me use it as a media center and Steam streamer on my TV.

However, I once did experiment with the VM notion and it is possible, but I don't know what kind of trouble you may run into when trying to publish apps to the app store.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have a mac and you don't plan on purchasing one, I would suggest you take a look at [Mac In the Cloud](http://www.macincloud.com/). I know some fellow developers who use that for Xamarin development.

Comment: Also have a look at the repost iOS simulator available in the alpha builds - this can really help test your app on iOS from a windows box by sharing just the iOS simulator from your remote mac

Comment: @JimBobBennett could you please tell me how those emulators work, I am a total newby in *Apple/Mac/iOS * subjects

Answer (score -1):

No, the virtual hadrware and drivers in hyper-v are generics... MacOs X is for hardware select from Apple.